# VMWare Fusion: Install MacOS from recovery partition is no longer available in 10.14?

Tags: mac, virtualization, vmware

In the old days I just install OSX virtual machine from the recovery partition.

[image]

But this is no longer available in newer Macs, any ideas?

P.S Recovery partition is actually available from diskutil

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         1.0 TB     disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.0 TB     disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            395.4 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 46.2 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                517.3 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
```

Comment: Pure guess... maybe VMWare can't read APFS?